# Convert date to string in Teradata

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

I'm trying to convert a date to string in Teradata. I've found on the Internet that it can be done like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

But this returns an error:

```
SELECT Failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'CURRENT_DATE'
keyword.
```

If I run that exact same command on another Teradata database I have access to, it works fine. I suspect it must be something regarding the version of Teradata, or something like that.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: That runs just fine for me...

Comment: @Andrew I've updated the question with something I just noticed. If I run that exact same query on another Teradata database, it works fine. Maybe there is something wrong with the version of Teradata running in the first database?

Comment: See what current_date returns on the two different systems maybe?

Comment: You might have a very old Teradata release (check `dbc.dbcInfo`) which doesn't support `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why you get this error, but you can do what you need also with this:

```
CURRENT_DATE(FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') (CHAR(8))
```

Comment: That returns '15/5/2019', so it seems as if it was still a date and not a string.

Comment: A bit shorter: `TRIM(Current_Date(FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'))`